# How to I test methods called in componentDidMount in a React Component correctly?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am writing unit tests for a scenario where the component fetches all the user's orders in componentDidMount. Before this i check to see if the session has timed out or if the user logged in and if not , redirect them to the signin page. For some reason my tests seem to be failing. How do I assert this scenario? My code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.checkCustomerCombinationState();
    this.props.actions.getMyOrders();
}

checkCustomerCombinationState = () => {
    if (TokenProvider.get('DP_USER_STATE') === '1' &&
      (cookie.load('DP_USER_STATE') === '0')) {
        TokenProvider.logout();

      window.location.assign(constants.navigateToSessionTimeout.mobile);
    }
}
```

Below are my Test cases:

```
describe('Test Cases for the Orders component', () => {
let wrapper;
let cdmStub;
let TokenProviderGetStub;
let TokenProviderLogoutStub;
let CookieLoadStub;

// let pushStub = sinon.stub(browserHistory, 'push');

beforeEach(() => {
    cdmStub = sinon.stub(Orders.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    TokenProviderGetStub = sinon.stub(TokenProvider, 'get');
    TokenProviderLogoutStub = sinon.stub(TokenProvider, 'logout');
    CookieLoadStub = sinon.stub(Cookie, 'load');

});

afterEach(() => {
    TokenProviderGetStub.restore();
    TokenProviderLogoutStub.restore();
    CookieLoadStub.restore();
    cdmStub.restore();

    wrapper.unmount();
});

it('Initial State is set properly', () => {

    wrapper = shallow(
        <Orders {...props} />
    );
    expect(wrapper.state().ordersStartNumber).to.equal(0);
    expect(wrapper.state().ordersEndNumber).to.equal(0);
});

it('MyOrders to be rendered', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(
        <Orders {...props} />
    );
    expect(wrapper.find('MyOrders').length).to.equal(1);
});

it('Correct props are passed to MyOrders', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(
        <Orders {...props} />
    );
    expect(wrapper.find('MyOrders').props().myOrders).to.deep.equal(ordersHistory.myOrders);
    expect(wrapper.find('MyOrders').props().actions).to.deep.equal(actions);
});

describe('componentDidMount was called with session timedout', () => {

    it('componentDidMount was called', () => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <Orders {...props} />
        );
        expect(cdmStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });

    it('User is logged out if the session has ended', () => {
        TokenProviderGetStub.withArgs('DP_USER_STATE').returns(1);
        CookieLoadStub.withArgs('DP_USER_STATE').returns(0);

        wrapper = mount(<Orders {...props} />)

        expect(TokenProviderGetStub.called).to.be.true;
        expect(CookieLoadStub.called).to.be.true;
        expect(TokenProviderLogoutStub.called).to.be.true;
    })
})
```

})

My last it block is failing with `AssertionError: expected false to be true`. However, the it block `componentDidMount was called` is passing. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to await for your component to mount.

```
it('User is logged out if the session has ended', async function(){
        TokenProviderGetStub.withArgs('DP_USER_STATE').returns(1);
        CookieLoadStub.withArgs('DP_USER_STATE').returns(0);

        const mounted = await mount(<Orders {...props} />);

        expect(TokenProviderGetStub.called).to.be.true;
        expect(CookieLoadStub.called).to.be.true;
        expect(TokenProviderLogoutStub.called).to.be.true;
    })
```